# mypy pop error for 'None' object is not iterable

Tags: mypy

Here I have a function like this:

```
def func_A(delta: Optional[List[int]],
           margin: Optional[List[int]]
           mode: str = 'OUT') -> Tuple[int, 
                                       Optional[List[int]],
                                       Optional[List[int]]]:

    result = 1

    if mode == "OUT":
        return result, [1,2,3], [4,5,6]

    elif mode == "IN":
        delta_x, delta_y = delta
        margin_x, margin_y = margin
        return result, None, None

    else:
        raise ValueError('wrong key')
```

however, when i use the function like below, mypy will pop error:

```
result, delta_options, margin_options = func_A(delta=None,
                                               margin=None,
                                               mode="OUT")
```

gives error:
    'None' object is not iterable

which part is wrong for my code? Thanks in advance.

P.S. my mypy configuration is below:

```
mypy --ignore-missing-imports --follow-imports=skip --strict-optional .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is L.10

```
delta_x, delta_y = delta
```

The type of delta is `Optional[List[int]]`. So delta can be `None`. If delta is None, the code does not work.

```
delta_x, delta_y = None
```

So you need to handle delta is None case before the code.

e.g.

```
if delta is not None:
    delta_x, delta_y = delta
```

or

```
delta_x, delta_y = delta if delta is not None else None, None
```

etc.